# how will changes made to a package that i depend on affect my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I just wanted to know if my flutter app depends on a certain package  and if the package has made some changes in its part how will it affect my app if I am only using one version of that package
say

```
dependencies
    flutter_eg:3.14
```

Comment: nothing will happen your app have the code from the previous version.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you mentioned, nothing happens and your app continues to use that exact version.

Take a look at [this](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints) to learn more about dependencies version constraints